# How do I reply to messaging extensions with the BotFrameworkAdapter?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have an bot which is setup using the BotFrameworkAdapter. I can see my message extension requests hit my server and can process these in my ActivityHandler.onTurn method. However, I cannot see how I can reply to these requests using the TurnContext.

In the examples, I have seen teamChatConnector.onQuery from the page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/messaging-extensions/search-extensions#nodejs but this is not using the BotFrameworkAdapter.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how I can do this using the latest BotFrameworkAdapter which I've been basing on the samples in https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples samples-work-in-progress branch. There also seems to be no examples surrounding this.

Comment: Are you just trying to reply to an incoming activity? I would recommend taking a look at the [EchoBot Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/samples-work-in-progress/samples/javascript_nodejs/02.echo-bot) for a simple example on how to respond to an incoming message. In the `bot.js` file in the [onMessage](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/155f365384b38a5f8138049a9b50cabffec302e0/samples/javascript_nodejs/02.echo-bot/bot.js#L11) function you can see they call `await context.sendActivity("...");` to respond to the user.

Comment: @tdurnford - I'm not trying to reply to a standard message, I am trying to reply to a search message extension.

Comment: @TobySmith- Could you please have a look at this [C# sample for SDK 4](https://github.com/clearab/Echo/blob/1aa9fb481c6a84f32c5683828e437753579597e9/Echo/EchoBot.cs#L99)? I'll check for node sample.

Comment: What search extension are you using and what is the incoming activity type?

Comment: Please check [this Node sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-node/tree/master/samples/message-extension-bot). Please let us know if you are facing any issues.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Wajeed-MSFT - I'm away from my desk today but will get back to you tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like messaging extensions are Teams specific functionality, and as a result the `botbuilder-teams` package should be used to make use of the Teams specific feature - specifically version `4.0.0-beta1`.

From the documentation in the README of botbuilder-teams, it states to add `adapter.use(new teams.TeamsMiddleware());` to extend the bot to support Microsoft Teams.

You can then make use of the `teams.TeamsActivityProcessor`. Setting this processor up in a way that provides the `invokeActivityHandler` with a `onMessagingExtensionQuery` method, as in the [sample shared by Wajeed](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-node/tree/master/samples/message-extension-bot), means that if you delegate your handling of messages to the processor, the messaging extension request will be handled.